# Translating Logistic Regression loss function to Softmax

Tags: java, logistic-regression, gradient-descent, softmax

I currently have a program which takes a feature vector and classification, and applies it to a known weight vector to generate a loss gradient using Logistic Regression. This is that code:

```
double[] grad = new double[featureSize];

        //dot product w*x
        double dot = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < featureSize; j++) {
            dot += weights[j] * features[j];
        }

        //-yi exp(-yi w·xi) / (1+ exp(-yi w·xi))
        double gradMultiplier = (-type) * Math.exp((-type) * dot) / (1 + (Math.exp((-type) * dot)));

        //-yi xi exp(-yi w·xi) / (1+ exp(-yi w·xi))
        for (int j = 0; j < featureSize; j++) {
            grad[j] = features[j] * gradMultiplier;
        }

        return grad;
```

What I'm trying to do is implement something similar using a Softmax regression, but all of the info of Softmax I find online doesn't exactly follow the same vocabulary as what I know about Logit loss functions, and so I keep getting confused. How would I implement a function similar to the one above but using Softmax?

Based on the wikipedia page for Softmax, I'm under the impression that I might need multiple weight vectors, one for every possible classification. Am I wrong?

Comment: You might want to consider moving this to the [math website](http://math.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 1):

The Softmax regression is a generalization of the Logistic regression. In Logistic regression, the labels are binary and in Softmax regression, they can take more than two values. Logistic regression refers to *binomial logistic regression* and Softmax regression refers to *multinomial logistic regression*.

There is an excellent page about it [here](http://ufldl.stanford.edu/tutorial/supervised/SoftmaxRegression/). In you code, you seem to try to implement gradient descent to calculate the `weights` minimizing the cost function. This topic is covered by the provided link.

> Based on the wikipedia page for Softmax, I'm under the impression that
>   I might need multiple weight vectors, one for every possible
>   classification. Am I wrong?

You are right. If you have *n* features and *K* classes, then your weights are *K* vectors of *n* elements as indicated on the link above.

Let me know if it helps.